# librospack not found when cross-compiling

Tags: cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble cross compiling ros for the Gumstix (overoevm).  I am using ROS Electric.  I am using a slightly custom distribution named commonos which is based on OpenEmbedded.  I have all my dependencies installed for my target (libboost, lib4cxx, etc.)

my custom rostoolchain cmake file looks like this:

```
set(TOOLCHAIN_FAMILY "commonos")
set(TOOLCHAIN_TUPLE "arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi" CACHE STRING "Toolchain signature identifying cpu-vendor-platform-clibrary.")
set(TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT "/opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi" CACHE STRING "Root of the target development environment (libraries, headers etc).")
set(TOOLCHAIN_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi"  CACHE STRING "Where to install headers/libraries etc).")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/bin/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi-gcc) # Make sure these are in your PATH
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/bin/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT} CACHE STRING "Cmake search variable for finding libraries/headers.")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER) # Don't search for programs in sysroot
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)  # Headers and libs from sysroot only
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(CMAKE_GENERATOR CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE TOOLCHAIN_FAMILY TOOLCHAIN_TUPLE TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT)
```

Then, when I do:

```
rostoolchain select commonos/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi
rosplatform select commonos/overo
rosprotect --unprotect --comms
rosprotect --pre-clean --comms
```

I get this error:

```
...
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libroslib.so
/opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/lib/librospack.so when searching for -lrospack
/opt/commonos/commonos-14_1/overoevm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-commonos-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lrospack
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
...
[ rosmake ] Cleaned 12 Packages.                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Built 7 packages with 1 failures.
```

So I guess librospack.so is not being compiled with the embedded target compiler?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34224/librospack-not-found-when-cross-compiling/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are now instructions for cross compiling ROS using Open Embedded: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0